# Tweepy can't find the UK

Tags: python, tweepy

I'm trying to get the Tweets for the United Kingdom using Tweepy. However, I'm only getting Arabic language?

```
tweets = tw.Cursor(api.search,
                   q=search_term,
                   lang="en",
                   since='2019-11-01').items(1000)
api2 = tweepy.API(auth)
places = api.geo_search(query="United Kingdom", granularity="country")
place_id = places[0].id
tweets = api2.search(q="place:%s" % place_id)
for tweet in tweets:
    print (tweet.text + " | " + tweet.place.name if tweet.place else "Undefined place")
```

Comment: Meaningful Arabic? Or just misinterpreted Unicode?

Comment: Meaningful Arabic @MadPhysicist

Comment: did you resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

The ID you're using is likely for "Hashemite Kingdom of Jordan":

```
>>> places = api.geo_search(query="United Kingdom", granularity="country")
>>> places[0]
Place(_api=<tweepy.api.API object at 0x00000201E04358B0>, id='fc6282dff859b848', name='Hashemite Kingdom of Jordan', full_name='Hashemite Kingdom of Jordan', country='Hashemite Kingdom of Jordan', country_code='JO', url='https://api.twitter.com/1.1/geo/id/fc6282dff859b848.json', place_type='country', attributes={}, bounding_box=BoundingBox(_api=<tweepy.api.API object at 0x00000201E04358B0>, type='Polygon', coordinates=[[[34.9427626, 29.1862444], [34.9427626, 33.3748822], [39.3011038, 33.3748822], [39.3011038, 29.1862444], [34.9427626, 29.1862444]]]), centroid=[36.31971222488649, 31.2805633], contained_within=[])
```

You can see that the United Kingdom is in fact one of the results though:

```
>>> [place.name for place in places]
['Hashemite Kingdom of Jordan', 'United Kingdom', 'United States', 'Kingdom of Saudi Arabia', 'United Arab Emirates', 'United States Minor Outlying Islands']
```

You should check for the name of each Place in the list to determine the one that corresponds with the United Kingdom before using it.